# How to fix web3 module AttributeError?

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

I am trying to using web3 in python.

I am trying to follow the steps in http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth

```
import web3
web3.eth.getBlock("1028201")
```

But got

> AttributeError: module 'web3.eth' has no attribute 'getBlock'

I tried in both python 3 and python 2.7, got the same result.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

The syntax you're using is wrong,
the attribute eth belongs to a WEB3 object, not the class itself
try this it shall work

```
from web3 import Web3
# Create an object from the WEB3 lib
w3 = Web3(Web3.IPCProvider())

#then use the eth attribute on it
w3.eth.getBlock("1028201")
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you are instantiating a `Web3` object as mentioned in the [quickstart docs](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/blob/master/docs/quickstart.rst#using-web3) before calling into `web3.eth.getBlock` to setup the `eth` module functions.

```
from web3 import Web3, TestRPCProvider
w3 = Web3(TestRPCProvider())
```

---

A look at the [code for web3.eth](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/blob/master/web3/eth.py) shows us that `class Eth(Module):` contains `def getBlock`. If you also look at the [definition of](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/blob/697cb000596ab670a0b84317199be534319d6074/web3/module.py) `Module`, you see see that the `attach` function is used to actually redefine `web3.eth` with the behavior you want.
The `attach` function is normally called in the `web3/main.py`:

```
for module_name, module_class in modules.items():
        module_class.attach(self, module_name)
```

Note in one of the loops above the `module_class` is `Eth` and `module_name` is `"eth"`.

You are likely missing this logic, so ensure you are instantiating a `Web3` object before calling into `web3.eth.getBlock`.

Answer (score 1):

I am working for Ethereum network. Given code works for me.

```
from web3 import Web3                               
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/"))
```

And then write code `web3.eth.getBlock("1028201")`

Answer (score 0):

Blocks can be looked up by either their number or hash using the `web3.eth.get_block` API. Block hashes should be in their hexadecimal representation. Block numbers

get a block by number

```
web3.eth.get_block(12345)
```

See doc.
https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#looking-up-blocks

Answer (score 0):

If anyone landed here in search of solution of below error like me

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'web3' from 'web3'
```

wrong: `from web3 import web3`
correct: `from web3 import Web3`
Please note capital 'W' in second 'Web3'

Comment: I can see the correct `from web3 import Web3` in some of the other answers already